# Unix Text Processing

Tags: books, tex-general, unix

In 1987 Dale Dougherty and Tim O'Reilly wrote a marvelous book [Unix Text Processing](http://oreilly.com/openbook/utp/) which is now freely available. The book gives tour the force introduction to the world of Unix text processing tools: vi, regex, sed, awk, Troff (various macros). Even though TeX was available at that time and vastly superior to Troff (at least for typesetting Mathematics) it has never been the part of the standard Unix installation and it will never be (kerTeX is the only reasonable distribution of TeX that could be considered a system tool).

I was wondering if anybody is aware of any project to write a TeX based "Unix Text Processing book" (My title would be "Unix TeXt processing book")? The potential audience for the book are power or would be power users, those folks who like to learn things once and use them all their lives.